# Visual Studio 2022 no muestra las referencias en el código

Tags: c#, visual-studio

acabo de instalar visual studio 2022 enterprise y veo que al inicio de los métodos no sale la información sobre las referencias. me ayudaba mucho para saber si estaba referenciado o no. He ido a las opciones y codelens está activado y no sé que puede pasar. ¿A alguien le ha pasado esto?

Desactive codelens y lo volví a activar pero sigue sin mostrar las referencias

Answer (score 0):

Busca Codelens, está en Opciones-> Editor de texto -> Todos los lenguajes -> Codelens.

Saludos.